# Facebook not using og metadata when shared from mobile device

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-opengraph

I have simple product pages populated with facebook open graph metadata. I've tested against the fb debugger and its being scraped successfully by fb. eg. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fshort.stylemology.com%2F1058

If I do a facebook share, from my pc, facebook shows the correct metadata on the sharing page, but when viewing the shared item on a wall, it points back to the simple product url rather than the full product url specified in og:url, but it still uses the og, description & image.

Mobile behaviour is even more erratic. Neither the url nor the description get used, but the correct image is displayed.

I've viewed the source on the mobile page and it is still being correctly populated with the open graph metadata.

Extremely confused and would appreciate any insight into this behaviour because my attempt to research this issues have come up dry.

Example simple product page:
http://short.stylemology.com/1058

thanks in advance for your feedback.

Comment: solution was that I had inadvertantly added a url query string to my sharing code which appeared to override the facebook og url. Quite useful actually.